# Facebook PHP SDK Login state parameter error

Tags: php, facebook

I've created a Facebook app which I want to use in a webpage. So, I've obviously followed Facebook docs for PHP SDK, so i read the login flow, and here comes the problem.

I'm simply trying to connect PHP to Facebook with Facebook Login, as described in [Facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login/5.0.0).

So, I've put my Facebook object into a class, and this is the code:
**class.socialmanager.php**

```
function __construct($_appID,$_appSecret,$_appCallback){
    $this->_fbAppCallback=$_appCallback;
    $this->_fbConnection=new Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id' => $_appID,
        'app_secret' => $_appSecret,
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
    ]);
    $this->_fbApp=new Facebook\FacebookApp($_appID,$_appSecret);
}
function getFBLogin(){
    $_fbLogin=$this->_fbConnection->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    $this->_fbPermissions=['public_profile','email','publish_actions'];
    return $_fbLogin->getLoginUrl($this->_fbAppCallback, $this->_fbPermissions);
}
```

And this is the **login.php**:

```
$_socialManager=new SocialManager(FB_APP_ID,FB_APP_SECRET,FB_APP_CALLBACK);
$_fbLoginURL=htmlspecialchars($_socialManager->getFBLogin());
<a href="<?php echo $_fbLoginURL; ?>">Register with Facebook</a>
<a href="<?php echo $_fbLoginURL; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
```

And finally this is the **callback.php**:

```
require_once('config.php');
global $_socialManager;
$_fbLogin = $_socialManager->getFbObject()->getRedirectLoginHelper();
try {
    $_fbAccessToken = $_fbLogin->getAccessToken();
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
if(!isset($_fbAccessToken)){
    /*
    if(isset($_SESSION['_driver']['_id'])) { header("Location:".SITE_URL.'modifica/nfb'); }
    else { header("Location:".SITE_URL.'login/nfb'); }
    */
} else {
    $oAuth2Client = $_socialManager->getFbObject()->getOAuth2Client();
    if (!$_fbAccessToken->isLongLived()) {
        try {
            $_fbAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($_fbAccessToken);
        } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
            echo "<p>Error getting long-lived access token: " . $_fbLogin->getMessage() . "</p>\n\n";
            exit;
        }
    }
    $_SESSION['_driver']['_fbAccessToken'] = (string)$_fbAccessToken;
    if(isset($_SESSION['_driver']['_id'])) { 
        global $_dbManager; 
        if($_dbManager->connectWithFacebook()){ header("Location:".SITE_URL.'modifica/fb'); } 
        else { header("Location:".SITE_URL.'modifica/nfb'); }
    }
    else { header("Location:".SITE_URL.'registrazionefb'); }
}
```

Everytime i got the same error: `Cross-site request forgery validation failed. The "state" param from the URL and session do not match.`

I've googled all day long, I've tried something like this [cookie solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32029116/facebook-sdk-returned-an-error-cross-site-request-forgery-validation-failed-th) and tons of other solutions, but no one helped me so far.

### Example

Using the cookie solution which I linked before, I've print my `$_COOKIE`, `$_SESSION` and `getLoginURL()` value, so here they are:

```
COOKIE:  [FBRLH_state]=>  ea243c89dd105a17f1e716f840a9c8d7
SESSION:  [FBRLH_state]=>  ea243c89dd105a17f1e716f840a9c8d7
URL: https://www.facebook.com/v2.2/dialog/oauth?client_id=820771421369364&state=ea243c89dd105a17f1e716f840a9c8d7&response_type=...
```

As you can see, there are all the same. But nothing is working at all.

Side note: This is not my 1st app on Facebook, I've just finished developing another one yesterday, but this app only is giving me problems, that's the strange thing that's making me mad. The funny thing is that I've copied/pasted the same functions I've been always using.

### Update

I think I've found something.
If i press the Facebook login button instantly when pages load, it works, after a few seconds it doesn't

P.S. all callbacks, app IDs and app secrets are correct, checked tons of times.

P.P.S. I've tried using Javascript SDK and it works ( obviously, I guess ). Don't know if this info can help someone

Comment: Did you try to clean $_SESSION['_driver']['_fbAccessToken'] before all token generation ?

Comment: @Fky yes, I've cleaned all session variables tons of time.

Comment: Check if your session is working properly. The `state` value gets stored in there, and if it is not available after the user gets redirected back to your app from the login dialog, that error occurs.

Comment: @CBroe The session variable `FBLH_*` is the same as it is in the login url, I'm sure of that because I've checked lots of times. Anyway, I'll check again on Monday

Comment: Make sure you are not calling `getLoginUrl` multiple times – it creates a new random `state` value every time.

Comment: @CBroe yep, I know that. I'm sure I'm calling that function only once on the login. I've copied/pasted my previous app's php files, copied/pasted original Facebook PHP SDK functions from the docs... Nothing working

Comment: We actually have a bug report about this which we are investigating what's going on. We believe it _could_ be a bug. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/778776425567156

Answer (score 0):

insert this code after $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

```
$_SESSION['FBRLH_state']=$_GET['state'];
```

and it wil work or for more detail visit [facebook login apps](http://zrclassroom.com/toturials/creer-une-application-facebook-connect-php-sdk-v5-207)