# Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required param "state" missing. Yii-2

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, yii2, facebook-php-sdk

So i've got login(here it called facebook) action in my controller, login-callback action and display action, where i want to view information using Facebook API. I've read about my problem and 've found that seems like my sessions are switched off, but i also read that in Yii-2 they are automatically switched on when an app is initialised. Also i tried it without framework, and it worked well. Maybe someone faced with such a problem in Yii-2?

**Login action**

```
**public function actionFacebook()**
{
    $fb = new Facebook([
        'app_id' => 'my_app_id',
        'app_secret' => 'my_app_secret',
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
    ]);
    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    $permissions = ['user_friends']; // optional
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://myblog.local/site/callback', $permissions);

    return $this->render('facebook', [
       'loginUrl' => $loginUrl,
    ]);

}
```

**Callback action**

```
**public function actionCallback()**
{
    $fb = new Facebook([
        'app_id' => 'my_app_id',
        'app_secret' => 'my_app_secret',
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
    ]);

    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    try {
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    } catch(FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    } catch(FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    if (isset($accessToken)) {
        // Logged in!
        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

        // Now you can redirect to another page and use the
        // access token from $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']

        return $this->redirect('/site/display',302);
    }
}
```

**Display action(where i want to view information using Facebook API)**

```
public function actionDisplay()
{
    $fb = new Facebook([
        'app_id' => '491899464333863',
        'app_secret' => 'f684b9467c548991cc3a91e028163e15',
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
    ]);

    // Sets the default fallback access token so we don't have to pass it to each request
    $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);

    try {
        $response = $fb->get('/me');
        $userNode = $response->getGraphUser();
    } catch(FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    } catch(FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    return $this->render('display', [
        'userName' => $userNode,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this session var has a value? Try the $fb->get('/me') with accessToken as a parameter

Comment: I tried to pass accessToken as a second parameter, it shows the same ;(

Comment: In actionDisplay $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] has a value?

Comment: Seems like it doesn't have a value, because i cant view a session value from actionDisplay() (it just prints Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required param “state” missing.), seems like this problem is in actionCallback or actionFacebook

Comment: IMHO the problem is in actionCallback, in try-catch block, it doesnt want to give me a token

Comment: Dump $S_SESSION array to see if your key is correct

Comment: Thx dude, thats was the key - it dumped nothing, i fixed the problem with session_start() before every action, i know that i can go something like Yii::$app->session->open(), but is it okay that the session wasnt working? I read that sessions in Yii open automatically...

Comment: I had a similar problem some days ago, and the issue was that my access token was in session with a different key, that's why i asked you to dump or see in debug toolbar the content of $S_SESSION. I'll post a answer to explain in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Yii2, changing `$S_SESSION` content will not work if you didn't open a session before with `session_start()`.

> When you access session data through the session component, a session
>   will be automatically opened if it has not been done so before. This
>   is different from accessing session data through $_SESSION, which
>   requires an explicit call of session_start().

**Source**: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-sessions-cookies.html

Yii2 has a class to manage sessions. So, you could store the *accesToken* in your **callback** action with:

```
$session = Yii::$app->session;
$session['accessToken'] =  $accessToken;
```

And then, in your **display** action:

```
$session = Yii::$app->session;
[...]
$fb->setDefaultAccessToken($session['accessToken']);
```

Remember that you could check the `$_SESSION` content with the debug toolbar.

More info: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-session.html

Answer (score 0):

You should really be setting up your own `PersistentDataInterface`. See this answer for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38116933/1062129