# Facebook login: Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required param "state" missing from persistent data

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

It appears I'm not the only one with this problem, but i've looked through all the previous threads on this topic and none of those solutions seem to be working for me.

I have a simple login.php page that should login to facebook upon click.  And login-callback.php to handle the redirect.

My callback page always returns "Facebook SDK returned an error: Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required param "state" missing from persistent data." no matter what I do.

I must be missing something obvious?

login.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
session_start();

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => '{id}',
    'app_secret' => '{secret}',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5'
]);

# login.php
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['email', 'user_likes']; // optional
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://{server}/login-callback.php', $permissions);



echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

login-callback.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if (!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}


require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => '{id}',
    'app_secret' => '{secret}',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5'
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
try {
    $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

if (isset($accessToken)) {
    // Logged in!
    $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you can find solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32029116/facebook-sdk-returned-an-error-cross-site-request-forgery-validation-failed-th

Comment: First of all, put `session_start` at the very beginning of the script, before any output.

Comment: I put session-start at the top of both pages - makes no difference.  The solutions from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32029116/facebook-sdk-returned-an-error-cross-site-request-forgery-validation-failed-th also do not work for me

Comment: For a major platform, got to say it. Facebook sucks wind big time.