# Allow user to register on a site by using facebook login api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am working with PHP and I am trying to allow user to register by using their facebook account. My work looks like this:

```html
<?php
    session_start();

    require_once __DIR__ . '/src/Facebook/autoload.php';

    # fb-callback.php
    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => '*************',
    'app_secret' => '***********************',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.6',
    ]);

    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

    try {
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {

        // When Graph returns an error
        //Graph returned an error

    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {

        // When validation fails or other local issues
        //Facebook SDK returned an error
    }

    if (isset($accessToken)) {
        // Logged in!
        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

        try {

            // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object

        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {

            //Graph returned an error

        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
            //Facebook SDK returned an error
        }

        //Rest of the code ...
```

In local, everything was cool but since the site is online, when I run the code, it works sometimes and most of the time, I get this error:

```html
Facebook SDK returned an error: 
Cross-site request forgery validation failed. 
The "state" param from the URL and session do not match.
```

Kindly help me solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32029116/facebook-sdk-returned-an-error-cross-site-request-forgery-validation-failed-th/34941215#34941215

Comment: Thanks, I have seen the comment and the token that I get after getLoginUrl() and before getAccessToken() are the same. So what can be the problem ?