# How fix Facebook login error in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, facebook-login

Facebook SDK returned an error:

> Cross-site request forgery validation failed. The "state" param from the URL and session do not match.

I use `fblogin()` and `fbcallback()` in same controller. But face this error. Also do all steps in developer.facebook.com. Session is also started. But error says, do not match.

```
public function fblogin(){



    $this->load->library('session');   
    $this->load->view('../libraries/facebook-php-sdk/src/Facebook/autoload.php');


    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id' => 'APP_ID', // Replace {app-id} with your app id
        'app_secret' => '{APP_SECRET}',
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',//v2.5
            ]);



    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

    // if (isset($_GET['state'])) {
    //     $helper->getPersistentDataHandler()->set('state', $_GET['state']);
    // } 
    // $sURL = $helper->getLoginUrl(FACEBOOK_AUTH_CALLBACK, FACEBOOK_PERMISSIONS);

    $permissions = ['email']; // Optional permissions
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://www.collegeprintsusa.com/maintenance/signin/fbcallback', $permissions);

   // echo '<a href="' . htmlspecialchars($loginUrl) . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
     header("location: ".$loginUrl);

}

public function fbcallback() { 


    $this->load->view('../libraries/facebook-php-sdk/src/Facebook/autoload.php');


    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([

     'app_id' => 'APP_ID',

     'app_secret' => 'APP_SECRET', 

     'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',//v2.5


    ]);

    // $serializedFacebookApp = serialize($fb);
    // $unserializedFacebookApp = unserialize($serializedFacebookApp);
    // echo $unserializedFacebookApp->getAccessToken();

    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();    //'https://www.collegeprintsusa.com/maintenance/signin/fblogin'
    // $_SESSION['FBRLH_state'] = $_REQUEST['state'];
    $permissions = ['email']; // optional

    try {

    if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {

    $accessToken = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];

    } else {

      $fbClient = $fb->getClient();
      $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken($fbClient);

    }

    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\facebookResponseException $e) {

    // When Graph returns an error

    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();

      exit;

    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {

    // When validation fails or other local issues

    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();

      exit;

    }

    if (isset($accessToken)) {

    if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {

    $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);

    } else {

    // getting short-lived access token

    $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

      // OAuth 2.0 client handler

    $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

    // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one

    $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);

    $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $longLivedAccessToken;

    // setting default access token to be used in script

    $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);

    }

    // redirect the user to the profile page if it has "code" GET variable

    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {

    header('Location: collegeprintsusa.com');

    }

    // getting basic info about user

    try {

    $profile_request = $fb->get('/me?fields=name,first_name,last_name,email', $accessToken);

    $requestPicture = $fb->get('/me/picture?redirect=false&height=200'); //getting user picture

    $picture = $requestPicture->getGraphUser();

    $profile = $profile_request->getGraphUser();

    $fbid = $profile->getProperty('id');           // To Get Facebook ID

    $fbfullname = $profile->getProperty('name');   // To Get Facebook full name

    $fbemail = $profile->getProperty('email');    //  To Get Facebook email

    $fbpic = "<img src='".$picture['url']."' class='img-rounded'/>";
    //  echo $fbid.','.$fbfullname; die();

    # save the user nformation in session variable
     $get_user_email = $this->user_model->get_single_user(['email' => $fbemail]);
     if($get_user_email){

          $res_user_fbid_update = $this->user_model->update_users(['id' => $get_user_email['id']],['facebook_id' => $fbid]);
        if($res_user_fbid_update){
          $this->session->set_userdata(['username' => $get_user_email['usename'], 
                    'name' => $get_user_email['name'], 
                    'last' => $get_user_email['last_name'], 
                    'email' => $get_user_email['email'], 
                    'type' => $get_user_email['user_type'], 
                    'uid' => $get_user_email['id'], 
                    'phone' => $get_user_email['phone'], 
                    'address' => $get_user_email['address'], 
                    'profile_image' => $get_user_email['profile_image'], 
                    'disable' => $get_user_email['sms_update']]);

                $this->output->set_output(json_encode(['result' => 1]));
                return FALSE;
            }else{
                $this->output->set_output(json_encode(['result' => 2]));
                return FALSE;
            }

     }else{
            $res_user_reg = $this->user_model->add_users([
                    'name' => $fbfullname,
                    'email' => $fbemail,
                    'phone' => 0,
                    'user_type' => 'customer',
                    'username' => $fbemail,
                    'password' => SALT . sha1($fbemail),
                    'token' => SALT . sha1($fbemail),
                    'facebook_id' => $fbid
                ]);

            if($res_user_reg){
                $this->output->set_output(json_encode(['result' => 1]));
                return FALSE;
            }else{
                $this->output->set_output(json_encode(['result' => 2]));
                return FALSE;
            }    

     }

    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {

    // When Graph returns an error

    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();

    session_destroy();

    // redirecting user back to app login page

    header("Location: index.php");

    exit;

    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {

    // When validation fails or other local issues

    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();

    exit;

    }

    } else {

    // replace your website URL same as added in the developers.Facebook.com/apps e.g. if you used http instead of https and you used            

    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://phpstack-21306-56790-161818.cloudwaysapps.com', $permissions);
    echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';

    }

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32029116/1531971 among others. What research have you done?

Answer (score 0):

Here I would like to suggest a better solution to log in with Facebook. Please use JavaScript instead of PHP, because PHP will redirect on facebook page & JavaScript will not redirect, It will open facebook login popup on own website, and it`s very quick & easy process according to performance.

Please follow below code to login with facebook using JavaScript.

```
$(document).ready(function($) {

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '186770818730407', // Set YOUR APP ID
          status     : true, // check login status
          cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        });
    };

    function fbLogin()
    {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
              getFBUserInfo();
            }else {
             showToaster('error','User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
             return false;
            }
        },{scope: 'email,user_photos,user_videos'});
    }

    function getFBUserInfo() {
        FB.api('/me',{fields: "id,picture,email,first_name,gender,middle_name,name"}, function(response) {
            $.ajax({
                url  : "http://example.com/welcome/facebook_login",
                type : "POST",
                data : {response:response},   
                dataType : "JSON",   
                beforeSend:function(){
                 ajaxindicatorstart();
                },       
                success: function(resp){
                   ajaxindicatorstop();
                   if(resp.type == "success"){
                        fbLogout();
                        showToaster('success',resp.msg);
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            window.location.href = base_url() + 'account-setting';
                        },1000);
                    }
                    else{
                        showToaster('error',resp.msg);  
                    }
                },
                error:function(error)
                {
                    ajaxindicatorstop();
                }
            });
        });
    }

    function fbLogout()
    {
        FB.logout(function(){ console.log('facebook logout') });
    }

    // Load the SDK asynchronously
    (function(d){
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));

});
```

Hope You will like it.

Thanks

Comment: When I use the this in my controller, i got this error.
'$email' says undefined and post 'blank' or 'null'

$email = $this->input->post('email');
       print_r($email);exit();

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined index: email</p>
<p>Filename: controllers/Fb_test.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 36</p>

Comment: Hi, On Controller print like that $response = $this->input->post('response'); Inside response variable you will get all details, please check ajax code carefully we are sending response variable. data : {response:response},

Comment: How insert unregistered user information in database. Can you please send controller code?

Comment: Unregistered user means ,  I use one facebook button. If user is already registered then they will logged in. But if user is unregistered, then that user would register using their facebook profile information. 
I want to do that functionalities.
My problem is, I don't get any value or data in 
$response = $this->input->post('response'); ,  and Insert blank data in database.
I can't register a user. 
How I fix it?

Comment: You can check if facebook unique id Or can also check with email id.

Comment: I'm already trying that, But not happen anything. Can you please send controller code?

Comment: I don't have it. simple you need to save facebook id in database once user came the first time, when user will visit again with same facebook account then using select query with where condition (facebook id), we can check it.